# Bounding an exponential row

Tags: real-analysis, summation, bounds-of-integration

Let $0<c<1$. I need to bound
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{c^{n-i}}{i}\leq C n^{-?}
$$

for some constant $C>0$. Does anyone know how to optimal bound this sum?
Thank you very much for any suggestions.

Comment: It is not considered acceptable to just ask a question on this site without showing your thoughts or attempts on the problem. This is not a homework service website. Maybe include the obvious things like the fact that the LHS is bounded above by a geometric series (which has sum...?). And what integral do you think is relevant to consider here also?

Comment: this trivially converges (i.e. $<\sum c^k$), so $Cn^0$